# How to get matching voronoi texture in 2.8?

Tags: texturing, shaders, versions

I have seen [this tutorial](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Rb8LO) and i don't know how to get matching settings in Blender 2.82.
Blender 2.82 has different Voronoi Texture node, and I can't follow the instructions.

*Old (2.7x) Voronoi texture*

[image]

Comment: maybe try to explain what kind of texture you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reccomend ignoring the other setting until you need them and just use the basic functions